# Running code when splash screen is shown in an MAUI application

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I want to run some code while the splash screen is shown in a MAUI application. The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen) has only instruction about the image (so far).

I assume I need to do a solution for each platform. I have tried to follow the [instruction for Xamarin on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen) and getting pretty close. I have created this `Activity`:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashActivity).Name;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
    }

    // Launches the startup task
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
        startupWork.Start();
    }

    // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
    async void SimulateStartup ()
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Performing some startup work that takes a bit of time.");
        await Task.Delay (3000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Startup work is finished - starting MainActivity.");
        //StartActivity(new Intent(MainApplication.Context, typeof (MainActivity)));
    }
}
```

My problem is that when `SimulateStartup` starts to run the UI is launching, despite `MainActivity` is never created.

Comment: Can't see what you actually want to do. Every piece of code that runs before the constructor of your initial page is executed while the splash screen is showing. Can't you do there what you need?

Comment: You don't need to do any of what you've done - just show an image. Add the code you need to any of the various methods that run while Maui App is starting up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In then end of MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp() I have added this:

```
var app = builder.Build();

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(4000);
    var bootstrap = app.Services.GetRequiredService<MyBootstrapService>();
    await bootstrap.SetupAsync();
}).Wait();

return app;
```

It works on Android. In Windows there are no splash screen, so user will se nothing until the bootstrapping is ready.